# How can I create Angular Grid column cell hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, hyperlink, angular-ui-router

I've angular grid and I want to create a link of a column cell with dynamic job id something like this /jobs/3/job-maintenance/general - here 3 is the job id. Let's say I've element.jobId available. How can I do it?

This is the existing column code -

```
<ng-container cdkColumnDef="jobName">
   <th cdk-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef>
      <span class="cursor-pointer" (click)="doSort('jobName')">Job Name</span>
      <span *ngIf="sortKey === 'jobName'"> {{ sortDirection === 'asc' ? '↑' : '↓' }} 
      </span>
   </th>
   <td cdk-cell *cdkCellDef="let element">
      <u *ngIf="!hasContainedName(element.jobName); else contain"
         class="text-primary cursor-pointer">{{element.jobName}}</u>
      <ng-template #contain>{{element.jobName}}</ng-template>
   </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Where is the problem? Have you tried `href="{{ yourLinkBuildingExpression }}"`? Or using routerLink if that's an internal link?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, href worked. Tricky part was populating dynamic value of jobid in href link. I used {{element.jobId}} to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for comments/help. Here is the solution worked correctly the way I wanted.

```
<ng-container cdkColumnDef="jobName">
                <th cdk-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef>
                  <span class="cursor-pointer" (click)="doSort('jobName')">Job Name</span>
                  <span *ngIf="sortKey === 'jobName'"> {{ sortDirection === 'asc' ? '↑' : '↓' }}</span>
                </th>
                <td cdk-cell *cdkCellDef="let element">
                  <u *ngIf="!hasContainedName(element.jobName); else contain"
                     class="text-primary cursor-pointer"><a href="/#/jobs/{{element.jobId}}/job-maintenance/general">{{element.jobName}}</a></u>
                   <ng-template #contain >{{element.jobName}}</ng-template>
                </td>
              </ng-container>
```